# How add two branch (master & develop) to redmine

Tags: git, redmine

I have installed Redmine on Debian. Also have Git with master (default) and develop branches.
I want to integrate git into redmine for showing this two branches in it.

But currently redmine show only master branch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading some tutorials....

Initial new project "testproject" in gitosis.
Add some users.

Edit **gitosis.conf**:

```
[group testproject]
members = user1 user2
writable = testproject
```

save it...

```
git add .
git commit -am 'add new project TESTPROJECT and users'
git push
```

ok. Let's create our new project:

```
mkdir testproject
cd mkproject
git init
git remote add origin git@192.168.48.15:testproject.git
touch readme.txt
```

change readme.txt

```
git add .
git commit -am 'init master branch'
git push origin master:refs/heads/master
```

ok. now we created master branch.
let's create develop branch:

```
git branch develop
git checkout develop
touch newfile.txt
```

change newfile.txt

```
git add .
git commit -am 'init develop branch'
git push origin develop:refs/heads/develop
```

Now we are created new repositories with two branches (master|develop)

In redmine setup path to our .../testproject/.git

it's all